# Gsheet MAXIFS with FILTERed range

Tags: google-sheets

I have two lists, one with vehicle IDs (column A) and dates they were used (Column B), another one with IDs (Column E) and all dates maintenance was performed on them (Column F). In Column C I would like a formula to return for each usage, the last time date when that specific vehicle was serviced.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux5H3.png)

I'm really bad at Gsheet so all I managed to do until now is to get the latest day a vehicle was serviced with this formula =MAX(FILTER(E$2:F, E$2:E=A2)). I'd need some way to add a condition where D<B. I tried a MAXIFS formula but I just don't have the knowledge to get the syntax right. Can anyone help?

Here's the expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKuE8.png)

Comment: Can you **manually** enter and showcase your expected output for the test data in the screenshot?! & elaborate on the condition you mentioned `D<B`

Comment: Hi, I've added the screen. Basically I want to know for each time the vehicle was used, when was the last time it was serviced. So if the vehicle was serviced AFTER that particular usage, the formula should ignore it. The way I would go about this is by taking the greatest date (MAX) where Maintenance date (D) is less than Use date (B).

Comment: I guess I should also mention that in some cases there won't be any data for maintenance, so in that case just return something like in the example: N/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try this single `array-style` formula(dont drag it down) in **Cell_C2**:*

```js
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(or(a="",b=""),,max(filter(F:F,E:E=a,F:F<b)))))
```

Comment: Wow, it just blows my mind that you can write something like that. It seems to be working!

Comment: Its kinda tough to create formulas *if you provide test data via screenshots* since it lacks the means for us to test the formula on! For future `1` You can easily share the sample sheet data via this [table generator](https://markdown-convert.com/en/tool/table). Just paste the *data rows/columns* in this generator→press enter→then copy-paste the data here in the question as a table→super simple. `2` you can also share a test sheet using this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) & is super recommended

Comment: That's awesome, I'll definitely use those in the future. Thanks again for your help!